# In a key: value object, what is the difference between outputting the value by the key and by an array?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following cases:

```
console.log({a: 1}.a);
console.log({a: 1}['a']);
```

They both output `1`, what is the difference between them? Which one should be used when outputting the value 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the second syntax you can have spaces, operators, variables and operations like:

```js
const keyPrefix = 'a';
console.log({'a+ 1': 1}[keyPrefix + '+ ' + (3 - 2)]);
```

That's not possible with the first syntax. *"Which one should be used when outputting the value 1?"* You have to use the second syntax if the first is not possible. In all other cases it's opinion based. They have same behavior. `{a: 1}.a` is syntax sugar for `{a: 1}['a']`.